# Teslacoin sync error - No Suitable Inputs Found

Tags: wallet, currencies, cryptography

Not sure this is the right forum for this, but I thought I'd ask out of desperation.

I have the following error when trying to sync my teslacoin wallet.

I managed to sunc about 6 weeks ago, however haven't been able to sync since then. I left it running overnight and get the error "No Suitable Inputs Found". I'm connected to the tesla network (I think, because I have 8 active connections).

My teslacoin version is v3.2.0.0 
The QT version it uses is 5.3.2

Hope that's enough information, if there's anything else required, please let me know and excuse my limited knowledge on crypto, still getting my head around it :)

Thanks

Norrinrad

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bitcoin and has no applicability to other topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated wallet to v3.3 and re-ran synch :)